# How do I get the contents of an http request in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

In PHP I can do this:

```
$request = "http://www.example.com/someData";
$response = file_get_contents($request);
```

How would I do the same thing in Ruby (or some Rails method?)

I've been googling for a half an hour and coming up completely short.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The standard library package `open-uri` is what you're after:

```
require 'open-uri'
contents = open('http://www.example.com') {|io| io.read}
# or
contents = URI.parse('http://www.example.com').read
```

Comment: How is this different than Net::HTTP?

Comment: In this case, not much. However that package does provide many useful shortcuts. Read the docs at http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/

Answer (score 11):

```
require 'net/http'
Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('http://www.example.com/index.html'))
```

Not sure why I didn't find this earlier.  Unless there's an better way, I'm going with this!

Answer (score 2):

Using the net/http library as shown:

```
require 'net/http'

response = Net::HTTP.get_response('mysite.com','/api/v1/messages')
p response.body
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view try

```
<%= request.inspect %>
```

Comment: Hmm ... maybe I wasn't clear, I'm trying to get something external, not in my app.

Comment: I was reading it as "How do I get the contents of a request object", not the contents of a web page, my bad.